# Use same paypal account for different websites

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

I have a paypal account and I want to use it for three of my websites. But I want to put different logos for each website payment page. I mean if the customer comes from site1 to paypal on the payment page I want to show the site1's logo. I also want to show unique email address for each website. Is that even possible through paypal.

I google it and find the following site.

http://www.e-junkie.com/bb/topic/546 (Please read second message - Shivani)

I am using php to integrate paypal. Please help. Thanks

Comment: yes its possible, all detains in the paypal docs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's possible. If you are using PayPal NVP approach in your API request, you can simply change the `HDRIMG` parameter on each of your website API request.

Say in your first website, you could have something like this:

```
$HEADERLOGO = "https://myurl.com/path_to_image/pic.jpg";

// Prepare PayPal NVP (Name-Value Pair) payment request
$nvp  = "METHOD=" . $SETMETHOD;
$nvp .= "&VERSION=" . $VERSION;
$nvp .= "&USER=" . $USERNAME;
$nvp .= "&PWD=" . $PASSWORD;
$nvp .= "&SIGNATURE=" . $SIGNATURE;
$nvp .= "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $PAYMENTACTION;
$nvp .= "&LOCALECODE=" . $LOCALECODE;
$nvp .= "&HDRIMG=" . $HEADERLOGO;

// run curl
```

Then on your second website, simply change the URL path of `$HEADERLOGO`.

Hope it helps.

Note: It's advisable to have the image source located in a **https** server.

[SetExpressCheckOut NVP API reference](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try that and let you know. Can i add different email address inside a paypal account?

Comment: What do you mean by different email address?